# Need to get last month only 3 letters JUL in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to print **JUL** and this query is returning **AUG**:

```
declare @a varchar(19)

set @a = left(datename(month, getdate()), 3)

print @a
```

But when I write my code as

```
declare @a varchar(19)

set @a = left(datename(month, getdate()), 3) - 1

print @a
```

I get an error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Syntax error converting the nvarchar value 'Aug' to a column of data type int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to **first** subtract 1 month from the current date, **THEN** convert it to a "date name":

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(19)

SET @a = LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, SYSDATETIME())), 3) 

PRINT @a
```

Comment: Thank you!!! marc it works as I expected, just we have to edit sysdatetime to getdate()

Comment: @RedDevil: `SYSDATETIME()` should be available in SQL Server 2008, and it's preferred over `GETDATE()`

Answer (score 1):

`getdate()` returns the current database system timestamp as a datetime value.

Since current month is August, it gives AUG.

```
set @a=left(datename(month,getdate()),3)-1
```

The above statement won't make the AUG to JUL.

You are trying to subtract 1 from a `varchar` type. Hence the error.